# Can these adverbs "often", "from time to time", "now and then", "sometimes" go with the present perfect tense?

Tags: grammar

Can these adverbs "often", "from time to time", "now and then", "sometimes" go with the present perfect tense?

> I've climbed mountains often since August, 2020.

> I've climbed mountains from time to time since August, 2020.

> I've climbed mountains now and then since August, 2020.

> I've climbed mountains sometimes since August, 2020.

Comment: They're all good except for the example with "sometimes". Can't tell you why just that one doesn't work while the others do.

Comment: What if I change the place of *sometimes* in the sentence: I've sometimes climbed mountains since August, 2020. Is it OK?

Comment: It's somehow better, but still not good

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to ELL, Stephen!

The tenses are OK. The word-order might be more natural as:

> I've climbed mountains often since August, 2020.
> I've **often** climbed mountains since August, 2020.

and

> I've climbed mountains sometimes since August, 2020.
> I've **sometimes** climbed mountains since August, 2020.

**But...**

Your sentences aren't colloquial and I can't imagine any context in which they might be spoken.

Climbing a mountain means reaching the top. If you *have* always reached the top you might say, "I've climbed several mountains..." Otherwise we would usually say, "I've often gone climbing..." or "I've done a lot of mountaineering..." rather than "I've climbed mountains [...] since August, 2020."

Where is the focus? It could be...

...on your prowess:

**Since August 2020 I've conquered many mountains**

...on the date:

**Because of** (or **Despite**) **[some event] in August 2020, *I've been able to* go climbing**

... or on the frequency:

**I've only occasionally** (or **I've very often**) **climbed mountains since August 2020**